# caret Confusion Matrix: Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : all arguments must have the same length

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have an academic problem and I am trying to run a confusion matrix on a decision tree prediction on my test set.  When I run the confusion matrix, I receive the error:

> Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : all arguments must
>   have the same length

Here is a sample from my code:

```
# create a basic decision tree on training set
tree1 <- rpart(working_well ~ amount_tsh + funder + basin,
                data = pump.train, method = 'class')

# predict using this tree, still on the training set.  Run the confusion matrix
table(predict(tree1, type = 'class'), pump.train$working_well)

# this works fine
cm1 <- caret::confusionMatrix(predict(tree1, type="class"), 
                       pump.train$working_well, positive = '1')

# now predict the tree on the TEST set
tree1_pred <- predict(tree1, pump.test, type="class")

# run the confusion matrix
predict_cm1 <- caret::confusionMatrix(predict(tree1, type="class"), 
                       pump.test$working_well, positive = '1')
```

That is where I get the error.  I searched the boards and learned that structure are not the same.  Both are factors with 2 levels.  However, tree1_pred has the following structure:

> Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
>    - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:11879] "1" "4" "8" "19" ...

The structure for `pump.test$working_well` is as follows:

> Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 ...

I assume the factors need the same exact structure to run the confusion matrix.  But I am at a loss for how to do this.  I'm not sure if it's even correct.

Any advice on how to fix this?  I know it must be easy but I'm stuck.

If more info is needed, let me know.
Thanks!!

Comment: it should be caret::confusionMatrix(tree1_pred, pump.test$working_well, positive = '1')?

Comment: otherwise predict(tree1) will just return the fitted values of tree1, which is prediction of your train data

Comment: Ughg.  Okay, thank you for the response.  I will check it out when I get the chance.